# Semantic meaning of 'indifférenciable' in French, as compared to English

Tags: anglais, sens, mathématiques, comparaison-de-langues, préfixes

In searching for a suitable translation of '*indistinguishable*', I found the French word '*indifférenciable*'.  http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/indistinguishable

From my point of view, as an Anglophone, I wonder something when comparing this French word to English '*indifferentiable*' (some would argue this isn't a word, but the colloquial meaning is "unable to differentiate"). I wonder if '*indifférenciable*' also carries the meaning "Unable to to differentiate", not only in the sense of comparing differences, but also in the sense of **derivatives and differentiation in the world of calculus.**

**My Question:**

Can the word '*indifférenciable*' imply 'unable to derive or differentiate' in the context of calculus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In mathematics, we use *non différentiable* for non-differentiable functions just like we use *non continue* for non-continuous functions.

*Indifférentiable* has no definite mathematical meaning, it's only used for “*impossible de trouver une différence*” (very close to *indistingable* which means similarly “*impossible à distinguer*”), and it might apply to functions as well.  “Deux fonctions non différentiables” and “deux fonctions indifférentiables” have different meanings.